# How to compare text field with mysql database field while typing on a php form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web

im facing a problem in my project. Here is simpler explanation in code parts. Let i have a mysql database named db having table named tb containing entries as follows:

```
table tb {

username: david, ford, sara, andrew
level: 22, 1, 3, 12

}
```

I have a form in index.php like:

```
<?php

..... let the submitted data is stored in these variables:
$username, $level;
?>

<form method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Level: <input type="text" name="level">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

I want that when user is typing in the username field. It automatically check in the database while on the time of typing if the currently being typed string matches with any of the equavilent mysql database field. if true, then it should warn and disable the submit button. if false then it should not warn and submit button enabled as well. For example: if user types david in username, then it should disable the register button because david name is already existed in mysql database.

Comment: first retrieve the data from the database, make it an array. now when typing match it with that array.

Comment: make a ajax call to check it, your username now in an array, you can encode array using `json_encode`. in jQuery detech the key you are typing and search for that key is in the array or not.

Comment: Simplest method, use the jQuery `keypress` function on the username field and use an ajax request to query the database.

Comment: making a database request with the `keypress` is not an good idea.

Comment: Check out this link `http://phppot.com/jquery/live-username-availability-check-using-php-and-jquery-ajax/`

Comment: im not familiar with ajax. i worked on php. may you please write the code for the given scenario? plz

Comment: Fakhruddin sir the link is not working.

Comment: Im not fammiliar with ajax. may someone please help me understanding. plz write code for the given scenario. thanks